# table style in external CSS file doesnt work

Tags: html, css

Im trying to get my style in my html file to an external CSS file. When I include the style in my HTML file it works, if I use it in an external CSS file it does nothing, but the other CSS in the file does work. I dont know how to put my code in the CSS file correctly. Does someone know? I just wanna know what to put in my css file to make it work.

```css
table, td, th {
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    text-align: left;
}

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

th, td {
    padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<table>
        <tr>
            <th>Naam docent</th>
            <th>Naam leerling</th>
            <th>Datum</th>
            <th>Leeftijd</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Comment</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Karen Karens</td>
            <td>Piet Pietersen</td>
            <td>12-12-2020</td>
            <td>6 jaar en 3 maanden</td>
            <td>voorbeeld@gmail.com</td>
            <td>dit is een voorbeeld!</td>
        </tr>

    </table>
```

Comment: Sounds like a path issue

Comment: Did you check the potential errors in dev tools? Network tab first to see if the URL of the stylesheet matches and later see the element styles. We will need more details.